# Why not expose List(Of String) in the parameters of web service in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, fxcop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Difference between List<T> and Collection<T> (CA1002, Do not expose generic lists)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232108/c-difference-between-listt-and-collectiont-ca1002-do-not-expose-generic)

The FxCop says in a rule that generic List should not be exposed to the outside world.

But I do not understand why and what is the replacement for the generice List?

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms182142%28en-us%29.aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that the use of a concrete `List<T>` is meant to be an implementation detail, and you're meant to expose something more abstract, such as `IEnumerable<T>` or `ICollection<T>`, that represents only the *functionality* you want to expose (such as being enumerable, mutable and/or indexable).  This gives you flexibility to change the implementation later on.

In practice, this warning is often resolved by returning `IList<T>` instead of `List<T>`, but the idea is to prompt you to think about "what *functionality* do I actually *need* to guarantee my callers?"  E.g. maybe I should be returning `IEnumerable<T>` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` because I don't want my callers messing with the returned collection.

Answer (score 2):

Always expose the lowest base class/interface in the object hierarchy that will be suitable for your scenario. For example if consumers of this property are going to only iterate over it use `IEnumerable(Of T)`. By exposing a `List<T>` you are breaking encapsulation by giving client code access to an implementation detail of your class.

Answer (score 1):

A generic list is a .NET construct, however web services are often intended to be interoperable with other frameworks.

Comment: Why? *"web services are often intended to be interoperable with other frameworks."* Read please. Not the best explanation, but it does answer why.

Comment: No, I didn't, would you like me to?

Comment: Web services are often designed to be interoperable for use as a loosely-coupled RPC mechanism when integrating heterogeneous systems.

Comment: +1 Had to think about it awhile, but I get what you are saying.

Comment: But the list will just be send as a list of strings by soap, rehargles of witch collection class/interface the webmethod uses.