# Fix Code Analysis Errors or violate Liskov Substitution Principle/make code much more inefficient

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I'm making `PriorityQueue<T>` classes, and right now I am using `List<T>` as a backing store.  The following are the errors that I have been getting:

Have Correct Suffix/ Do not have incorrect suffix

Do not expose `List<T>`

For the -Queue suffix I need to inherit `Queue<T>`, but to sort a `Queue<T>`, I would need to empty the queue, sort, and then refill the queue.  Also, if I inherit from `Queue<T>`, I would violate LSP because a priority queue is not a FIFO collection.

For one of the types of PriorityQueues that I am making is using an `IComparer<T>` to compare the elements, but `IComparer<T>` is only supported on arrays and `List<T>`.

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232108/c-difference-between-listt-and-collectiont-ca1002-do-not-expose-generic), but it doesnt fully relate to my question.

So here are my questions:
Should I suppress these code analysis warnings?
Should I inherit from `Queue<T>` and rewrite my classes to work off of it, even though it is less efficient?
If not, should I still swap out `List<T>` for something else?

Edit:
I don't know if this would make any difference, but the following is my setup of each of my classes:

- `PriorityQueue<T>` -- abstract base class (Sort() is abstract)
- `PriorityQueue<T, TComparer>` -- subclass that uses a comparer to
  sort
- `ReflectionPriorityQueue<T>` -- subclass that uses reflection to
  sort, specifics not important to this question.

Comment: Is the `List<T>` a (private) backing store or the base class?

Comment: Code analysis is used to identify *likely problems*, and make *suggestions* about how to avoid them. If your code will be more efficient/easier to read/etc. by ignoring the suggestions, then by all means do so. (Though if your `List<T>` backing store is `public`, you should definitely make it `private`.)

Comment: Are you exposing the list directly on a public interface?

Comment: The list is a private field that is then exposed through a read-only protected property.  It is not public.

Comment: @JKor Shouldn't be exposed protected either - "protected" is still part of the public API, as another assembly can subclass you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These errors have nothing to do with using a `List<T>` - they're about the public API.

> Have Correct Suffix/ Do not have incorrect suffix

This one is debatable - personally, I'd disable this warning, as a `PriorityQueue<T>` should, in my opinion, use the name `PriorityQueue<T>`.

> Do not expose List

This just means you can't *publically* expose the `List<T>` as a `List<T>`.  If you're encapsulating the list, this should never appear.  As long as you keep your list *private*, this warning should go away.

> Should I inherit from Queue and rewrite my classes to work off of it, even though it is less efficient? If not, should I still swap out List for something else?

I suspect the problem is that you're trying to subclass `List<T>`, which is a bad idea.  Encapsulate it as a private member, and implement the *appropriate* interfaces instead.

Comment: I am not trying to subclass `List<T>`.  Currently I am just implementing `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Im just implementing the GetEnumerator method of the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: @JKor See my other comment - you can't have the List be part of your public API (including via a protected property)